# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED....by tamoghna

Tags: android

I have a problem with the Google maps activity......I'm getting the error of Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED........following  code of Google maps activity.............

```
 package com.tommy.maps;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Main extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.e("key", "ok");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Log.e("key", "ok2");
        }
    }
```

---

xml file in layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

---

androidmanifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.tommy.maps"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.tommy.maps.Main"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="API_KEY" />
            <meta-data>
            </meta-data>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I have posted the manifest and xml code and java code ......please tell me my error and tell me what to do for the error......
my log cat messages are:-

```
12-26 15:06:00.160: I/Choreographer(546): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-26 15:06:00.330: I/Choreographer(546): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-26 15:06:00.600: I/Choreographer(546): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

12-26 15:06:01.361: D/AndroidRuntime(1480): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<

12-26 15:06:01.361: D/AndroidRuntime(1480): CheckJNI is ON

12-26 15:06:01.470: D/dalvikvm(1480): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0

12-26 15:06:01.490: D/dalvikvm(1480): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0

12-26 15:06:01.590: D/dalvikvm(1480): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

12-26 15:06:01.590: D/dalvikvm(1480): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0

12-26 15:06:01.770: E/cutils-trace(1480): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Check out my answer and try to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As you minimum api  level is 8 so you need you `SupportMapFragment` besides `MapFragment` in your xml file. Change your layout as below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In your `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity` besides `Activity` as below:

```
 public class Main extends FragmentActivity{
```

Comment: Sir ,i followed ur suggestion but also i'm getting the same error.....and in the log-cat i'm getting the error"Error opening trace file:No such file or directory (2)" and the tag is "curtails-trace".........sir plz suggest now what to do?

Comment: Error is :- "Error opening trace file:No such file or directory" as shown in log-cat and " error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" in my console (NOTE:- i'm using eclipse interface)

Comment: Sir i've posted it....all the messages that the log-cat gives when i run the application in the emulator (Emulator specifications: Device:2.7" QVGA (240x320 :ldpi)  Target:Google APIs(Google Inc.)-API Level 18   )

Answer (score -1):

Try to place this in your xml file: `<fragment....../>`

and even try to generate api key try to place it....

and  even

Just delete "gen"folder . It build automatically.
Application will work fine.

Comment: Its not error actually its his typo mistake while posting the question.

Comment: Does it make any difference ? Check out OP question and your answer. Its just same